# Intermittent results from AJAX PHP request

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-chosen

I have a select group populated by `AJAX/PHP`.

The issue i have although it works perfectly well, it does not return results 100% of the time of the page load.

Is there a specific reason why this might be happening?

**the html**

```
<div id='select_tags_div'>
</div>
```

**the AJAX**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    selector_refresh();
});

function selector_refresh() {
        url = '/home/bin/scripts/tags_list.php';
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url, 
                dataType: 'html',
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#select_tags_div").html(result);
                    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
                    $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
                    vid_tags();
                }
        });

}
```

[image: When it fails]

[image: When it succeeds]

I have checked the source on the both success and fail to show results, and the results actually are not populated at all. I thought it may have been a chosen.js issue but now its looking like it isn't that at all. Instead it seems it may be a PHP/AJAX issue not returning the results.

When i check the AJAX success with an alert, it confirms the AJAX is successful even on the times when the PHP has not populated correctly.

**ADDED**
I added a button which calls the function to populate the field, of which functions 100% of the time.

Could this be a case of DOM perhaps?

Comment: Enabling a development tool on your browser like Firebug would be helpful then you can see the result of the Ajax call and the response that was sent from PHP.

Comment: Are you using a database connection in your php script? Perhaps you're consuming all available open connections that you're allotted due to the fact that you never close your SQL connection?

Comment: I added a button to test the function of what populates the options and that works everytime without fail. Could it be that the element isn't loaded in the DOM before the ajax executes everytime?